How do I return to the smart guide and anchor behaviour from Illustrator CC 2021?
I have recently moved from Adobe Illustrator CC 2021 to Adobe Illustrator CC 2023 and I can't help but notice that the behaviour of the programme has been significantly changed.
Previously when I move my mouse pointer to the edges or centre of an object a line would appear to indicate that it is aligned with said object, now these lines do not appear unless I really precisely move my mouse close to the edges or centre.
Another thing is that if I move my mouse pointer on a path it used to say intersect and indicate that I am in fact on top of a path, it doesn't do that anymore.
This has become a big problem with alignment, I can't for example create a rectangle at exactly the bottom of another shape, or I can't draw a path and place a new point as an intersect on top of an existing path, likewise the scissors tool never tells me when I am hovering over a path.
Curiously, the old behaviour does return when I have any rectangle or ellipse selected. This doesn't work if I have any other shape selected. This means this workaround doesn't work for drawing shapes and paths since I will have that current path or shape selected.
I have tried tweaking settings under Preferences, both under Selection & Anchor Display and Smart Guides, but to no avail.
Is there a way to consistently return to the old Adobe Illustrator 2021 behaviour without me needing to have a random rectangle selected?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I haven't noticed these issues and can't reproduce them. Smart Guides appear to work just fine. Have you tried resetting the preferences perhaps?  Not sure this is answerable ultimately as it's pretty hard to compare an older version with a newer version like this because it would require access to both pieces of software.

I have just reset CC 2023 preferences and the same problem persists. The only way to get smart guides to work properly is to have a rectangle or ellipse selected.

I can't reproduce this.  Smart guides seem to be working fine no matter what is or isn't  selected in my copy of CC 2023.  This is perhaps something you need to contact Adobe about.  Tech support is generally off-topic here. Sorry about that.

Once Adobe changes something at the core of the app, the only way to revert it is to use an older version.
